# Is there an easy way to determine if user input is an integer in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a new student to bash scripting, and I am stumped on an assignment question.
I was wondering if there is an easy way to determine whether a users' input is an integer or not.  More specifically, if a user is prompted to input an integer, is there a quick check to validate?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is kind of a kludge, it's using -eq for something other then what it was intended, but it checks for an integer, if it doesn't find an int it returns both an error which you can toss to /dev/null and a value of false.

```
read input
  if [[ $input ]] && [ $input -eq $input 2>/dev/null ]
  then
     echo "$input is an integer"
  else
     echo "$input is not an integer or not defined"
  fi
```

Comment: This assumes /dev/null exists

Comment: It also assumes the argument is not empty

Answer (score 41):

One way is to check whether it contains non-number characters. You replace all digit characters with nothing and check for length -- if there's length there's non-digit characters.

```
if [[ -n ${input//[0-9]/} ]]; then
    echo "Contains letters!"
fi
```

Another approach is to check whether the variable, evaluated in arithmetic context, is equal to itself. This is bash-specific

```
if [[ $((foo)) != $foo ]]; then
    echo "Not just a number!"
fi
```

Comment: If input is 5b for example, it will fail check.

Answer (score 17):

You can test by using Regular expression

```
if ! [[ "$yournumber" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; 
 then exec >&2; echo "error: Not a number"; exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This is the most literal, and therefore easiest to remember.

Answer (score 3):

I found this post http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/21668-how-check-whether-string-number-not.html that talks about this.

If your input does not need to check if there is a +/- on the number, then you can do:

```
expr $num + 1 2> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    echo "Val was numeric"
else
    echo "Val was non-numeric"
fi
```

Comment: Simplest for integers. But doesn't support decimal fractions like 1.1, 1.2 etc

Comment: `expr "$num" + 1 > /dev/null 2>&1` will avoid the value of `$num + 1` being echoed to the stdout. Quotes around `$num` are there for safety. (in case `$num` has something with spaces in it like `Foo Bar`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it. It's probably a bit more elaborate than needed in most cases, but would handle decimals also. I had written the below code to get rounded number. It also checks for numeric input in the process.

```
    #--- getRound -- Gives number rounded to nearest integer -----------------------
    #    usage: getRound <inputNumber>
    #
    #    echos the rounded number
    #    Best to use it like:
    #      roundedNumber=`getRound $Number`
    #      check the return value ($?) and then process further
    #
    #    Return Value:
    #      2 - if <inputNumber> is not passed, or if more arguments are passed
    #      3 - if <inputNumber> is not a positive number
    #      0 - if <inputNumber> is successfully rounded
    #
    #    Limitation: Cannot be used for negative numbers
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    getRound (){
        if [ $# -ne 1 ]
        then
            exit 2
        fi

        #--- Check if input is a number
        Input=$1
        AB=`echo A${Input}B | tr -d [:digit:] | tr -d '.'`
        if [ "${AB}" != "AB" ] #--- Allow only '.' and digit
        then
            exit 3
        fi
        DOTorNone=`echo ${Input} | tr -d [:digit:]` #--- Allow only one '.'
        if [ "${DOTorNone}" != "" ] && [ "${DOTorNone}" != "." ]
        then
            exit 3
        fi

        echo $Input | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}' #--- Round to nearest integer
    }

    MyNumber=`getRound $1`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Empty or invalid input passed"
    else
        echo "Rounded input: $MyNumber"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me, handling empty input case.

```
if [ $input -eq $input 2>/dev/null -o $input -eq 0 2>/dev/null ]
then
   echo Integer
else
   echo Not an integer
fi
```

Comment: *${input:-0} -eq ${input:1}* should work as well, I suppose. (It’s about empty argument only)